# Azure Function Service Bus Trigger when ordering is essential?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

We have an Azure Function which consumes messages from a Service Bus topic. This 'EntityUpdated' topic holds messages which record changes to an entity.

It's therefore essential that these messages are processed in the order they appear on the bus.

The problems we have are:

- the function will scale, and therefore competing consumers will process some messages quicker than others
- we don't want to remove a message from the queue if we fail to process it

What's an appropriate solution we can undertake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can restrict scale out in Azure Functions, set the limit to 1 so that it does not scale. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#limit-scale-out). Also take look here at an [article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/ordering-messages-in-azure-service-bus/) where a following kind of problem is discussed by maintaining order in Service Bus. Also take a look [here](https://dev.to/azure/ordered-queue-processing-in-azure-functions-4h6c) for a similar problem and solution, a great article.

Comment: The last article you mentioned is extremely useful! Only remaining thought now is what happens if a consumer fails to process a message, is it possible to keep the session lock, and not remove the message from queue until we confirm it has been successfully processed?

Comment: You can use exception handling the way it shown here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues#receive-messages-from-the-queue. In this second article read the 'Receive Modes' sub-heading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-queues-topics-subscriptions